# Steam In home steaming not working on Chrome OS (via crouton)

Tags: debian, networking, chroot, chrome-os, steam

I installed Debian stretch via crouton, and after navigating through "locales" problems, mounting problems, and video problems, I managed to get it to work very well on my Asus C202.

However all network functions are blocked, including the network manager found in gnome settings. When I run Steam, the other computers on the LAN don't recognize it at all, and the Chromebook does not see other devices on the network when in chroot (ssh and media sharing doesn't work, as if I am offline).

How can I configure Chrome OS to make itself visible on the network, and/or allow chroot to manipulate it?

Comment: there are options within Chrome os to manually set IP address, subnet, and gateway, as well as setup proxy if it can be used in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If people are still having problems, the following commands worked well for me:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 27031 -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 27036 -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 27036 -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 27037 -j ACCEPT
```

as well as the later suggested

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 37804 -j ACCEPT
```

I input all of them into the Chrome shell (I mean crosh, NOT inside the chroot or the host computer), and got both Steam to recognize other computers on the LAN, and game streaming to work. Tested video, and mouse keyboard input, all of which work without any problems. Did not test sound however, but I'm sure it works as well.

To find this I had to navigate through one post referring to the other, in the end it was on reddit:
 https://www.reddit.com/r/Crouton/comments/1xj9qz/has_anyone_been_able_to_use_steam_inhome_streaming/chi5m30/